# percentEven, won't compile

Tags: java

So this is the percentEven method from the Java textbook. I cannot get it to compile and was wondering if you guys could see my mistake.

"Write a method called "percentEven" that accepts an array of integers as a parameter and returns the percentage of even numbers in the array as a real number."

that is the instructions. this is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.*;

public class percentEven {

   public class void main ( String [] args ) {
      int [] integers = {34, 56, 4, 17, 9, 83, -300, 5};
      int evenResult = percentEven (integers);
      System.out.println ( " The percent of even numbers is" +          evenResult + "." );
   }

   public class int percentEven ( int [] integers ) {
      int count = 0;
      int even = 0;
      for (i=0,i<integers.length,i++){
         if ( integers[i] % 2 == 0 ){
            even++;
         }
         count++;
      }
      count= (even/count)*100;
      return count;
   }
}
```

Comment: Also ignore some of the weird spacing, first time posting a question on here.

Comment: How did you try to compile it? What was the error message?

Comment: The `class` modifier should only be used for introducing a class, not a method. Remove the `class` modifier from lines `5` and `11` to start. Also, check your loops some.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to get an IDE such as [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/mars2).

Answer (score 2):

You declare your method wrong.

```
public class
```

denotes a new class. What you mean to write is

```
public static int percentEven
```

Your loop should also be delimited by ; not , characters.

Answer (score 2):

First, change

```
public class int percentEven ( int [] integers ) {
```

to

```
public int percentEven ( int [] integers ) {
```

percentEven is a method, not a class.

Second, change

```
for (i=0,i<integers.length,i++){
```

to

```
for (int i = 0;i < integers.length; i++){
```

Using IDE for Java development would be a good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

You had a bunch of places where you wrote `class` in a function. Your `main` needs to be `static`. Since it is calling another function `percentEven`, that function should be `static` too. I will avoid going into a further technical details here.

For-loops had `,` where you needed `;`.

There was a mistake in the part where you were doing a percentage calculation. `int`/`int` gives an `int`; so, 4/8 = 0. Multiplying it by 100 makes as little as no difference. You get 0, when you should get 50. I changed it to a `double` so that you can understand the arithmetic. It's working code now.

Following is working code.

```
public class PercentEven {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] integers = new int[]{34, 56, 4, 17, 9, 83, -300, 5};
      double evenResult = percentEven(integers);
      System.out.println("The percent of even numbers is " + evenResult + "." );
   }

   public static double percentEven( int[] integers ) {
      int count = 0;
      int even = 0;
      for (int i = 0 ; i < integers.length ; i++){
         if ( integers[i] % 2 == 0 ){
            even++;
         }
         count++;
      }
      return (100.0*even/count);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several errors in the code:

1. `percentEven` is a `method` not a class, remove that keyword class
2. you cannot make a static reference to the non-static method, so the method must be static
3. the variable `i` in the for loop must be declared and the content is with semicolon not colon

## final code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] integers = {
        34, 56, 4, 17, 9, 83, -300, 5
    };
    int evenResult = percentEven(integers);
    System.out.println(" The percent of even numbers is" + evenResult + ".");
}

public static int percentEven(int[] integers) {
    int count = 0;
    int even = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
        if (integers[i] % 2 == 0) {
            even++;
        }
        count++;
    }
    count = (even / count) * 100;
    return count;
}
```